# Kinetic theory postulates and Van der Waals

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

What was the purpose to assume that gas molecules are point particles? What could be explained through this postulate? Also when we refer to kinetic theory the postulates of this theory are the modified postulates of van der Waals? Can we derive ideal gas law from van der Waals equation?

Comment: The van der Waals equation reduces to the ideal gas law at large specific volumes.

Comment: Yes but i cant understand what happens when molecules have less space to move

Comment: Yes but i cant understand what happens when molecules have less space to move